When running multiprocessing with sqlalchemy I'm getting this error in Pycharm:
I'm having this error.
The rows are inserted in database, but getting this error in pycharm, and it wont finish the loading on browser.
def _insert_objects(temp_car_list):
    sess = Session(engine)
    sess.add_all(temp_car_list)
    sess.commit()
    

def _create_cars_list():
    car_names: list[str] = ['BMW', 'Mercedes', 'Toyota', 'Opel', 'Tesla']
    car_colors: list[str] = ['blue', 'yellow', 'black', 'white', 'green']
    seat_colors: list[str] = ['blue', 'yellow', 'black', 'white', 'green']

    temp_car_list = []
    for _ in range(100000):
        temp_seat_list = []
        for _ in range(2):
            seat = Seat(
                farve=random.choice(seat_colors),
                height=random.randint(100, 130)
            )
            temp_seat_list.append(seat)

        bil = Bil(
            name=random.choice(car_names),
            color=random.choice(car_colors),
            seats=temp_seat_list
        )
        temp_car_list.append(bil)

    return temp_car_list


@bp.route('/multi', methods=['GET'])
def multi():
    start_time = time.perf_counter()

    car_list = _create_cars_list()
    processes = 7
    chunk_size = 1000
    chunks = [car_list[i:i + chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(car_list), chunk_size)]
    print(len(chunks))
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=processes) as poool:
        poool.map(_insert_objects, chunks)
        poool.close()

    end_time = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'Time taken: {end_time - start_time} seconds')

    return 'multi DONE'

when I run this, the code runs in infinite loop and browser tab is not stopping.
however the rows ARE inserted in database.
if I make it a larger number, and run it with apply_async, my pc crashes as RAM fill up pretty fast.
the error after inserting in pycharm is:
Exception ignored in: <bound method InstanceState._cleanup of <sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState object at 0x7f5d4d88fe30>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/terfy/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py", line 514, in _cleanup
    def _cleanup(self, ref: weakref.ref[_O]) -> None:

  File "/home/terfy/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 452, in <lambda>
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, lambda *args: sys.exit(0))
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^
SystemExit: 0

any help will be appreciated.
thank you.
